# Is there a way to change permission of Desktop Pictures folder?

Tags: permission

In `System/Library/Desktop Pictures` there are a lot of desktop wallpapers.

I like to open them in photoshop, add some text and then save them there again.

Is there a way to change the permission of that folder as to allow be to add  my own pictures?

I tried the usual - get info -> open the lock, change to read and write.

I get the error "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission." but I thought I was the admin user!

Comment: What version of MacOS?

Comment: @Seamus, You asked "What version of MacOS?" and the path in the OP is shown as `System/Library/Desktop Pictures` which would mean **macOS Catalina**.  What you propose in your answer as far as "Once you've gotten the Get Info window open in Finder, click the lock, authenticate yourself (as an admin user). After that, you can change the permissions for group wheel to Read & Write."  will not work in **macOS Catalina** due to SIP and the e.g. Macintosh HD is  mounted as read only.  You'd have to disable SIP and the mount `/` as read-write and there still may be issues.

Comment: @user3439894: Thanks for that feedback. I was not aware this had changed in Catalina, and I checked my answers on my Mojave 10.14.6 system. I've got a Catalina system, so I'll go through the same drill there & update as required. Maybe that's why bmike placed his edit at the top of my answer :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MacOS 'Catalina' (or earlier): An alternative that's easier (and safer?) to changing permissions, and may achieve your objective:

> Apple lets you choose an arbitrary folder for Desktop Pictures, so copy everything you want to a folder in the /Users/Shared or your /Users home folder and modify them to your pleasing.

Here's how: To add folders you already own to your choices for Desktop graphics, use the *"Desktop dialog"* as shown below. Simply right-click any desktop & select `Change Desktop Background` to access this dialog.

[image]

For pre-Catalina systems (the following works on my Mojave system), the `Desktop Pictures` folder is located in `/Library/Desktop Pictures`. It's also `hidden` by default, so you must enter `open /Library` at the CLI to see it. However, once you've found it in `Finder`, you can change the permissions.

There are several ways to set the permissions you need, but let's use the approach w/ `Finder`: Once you've gotten the `Get Info` window open in Finder, click the lock, authenticate yourself (as an admin user). After that, you can change the permissions for group **`wheel`** to `Read & Write`. Once you've selected the `Read & Write` permissions, you must click the small gear at the bottom of the window, and "Apply" the changes. At this point, you'll be presented with a confirmation dialog similar to this:

[image]

Once this has been completed, you should be able to add and delete (or modify) any pictures in `/Library/Desktop Pictures`.

Comment: @bmike: Thanks for the edit, it's good input. I've re-edited to move it to a different place in my answer. Lemme' know if you've any feedback.

Comment: I have Catelina. added a folder as you indicated in the screenshot, the folder goes where you have "ArtWallpapers". The I went to the folder `System//Library/Desktop Pictures` and tried to change permissions (or delete it now) and I get "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission."

Comment: @relidon: I'm not sure you should change or delete `System//Library/Desktop Pictures` (actually `System/Library/Desktop Pictures`, right? ). In other words, in ***Catalina*** you will use the folder you added **in addition to** this *default* folder. Is that acceptable??

Comment: Ah ok I get it! I was hoping I could delete (or modify the contents of) the default folder. I like those default wallpapers I just like to photoshop a quote on top of them. *Since the folder is 2GB big, I thought I could modify/delete from there*. So I'm assuming that can't be done? **the wheel for the original folder doesn't change.**

Comment: @relidon: I don't think it's easy on `Catalina`. Based on a comment to your question (ref @user3439894), Apple's *new and improved SIP* is behind this. There are some articles online describing how to [disable SIP](https://howtomacos.com/2019/11/01/disable-system-integrity-protection-in-macos-catalina/), but I've not tried it myself, and therefore can't recommend it.

Comment: I'm not that confident to do that, I'll leave it as it is. Thanks for your time

Comment: Neither am I - yet... I'm staying on the sidelines until this gets worked out. There's an [oft-cited review of Catalina on Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/10/macos-10-15-catalina-the-ars-technica-review/) that's worth reading. The author implies that *the situation* wrt Catalina's new security features may get worse before it gets better. That said, at 10.15.3, we may already be into the worst of it. Wrt these "security improvements", I feel a bit like St. Augustine: *"Grant me chastity and continence, but not yet."*